# Connecting Pi's ground to external ground

Tags: pi-3, electronics

i'm currently working on a system that requires an external power supply to drive all the peripherals. I'm using a 10A 12V supply with voltage regulators to achieve the required voltage levels.

I need to connect the Pi's ground to the external ground so that they have the same reference. What's the safest way to do this? Can I simply connect the grounds directly or is that too risky for the pi?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using one or more GPIO to control the peripherals?  If so you need to connect the peripheral and Pi grounds.  If the 12V power supply ground is common to the peripherals that would be an appropriate ground point.

Comment: The peripherals get power from the external. So i'll just connect the ground of the external to that of the pi. thanks.